# pygetwindow Error, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'topleft'

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to get a screenshot of a specific  window, but I get the following Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'topleft'. How can I solve it ?

```
import pygetwindow
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image
import platform

path = 'report/result.png'
titles = pygetwindow .getAllTitles()

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('bachelor-project-vision-based-traffic-scene-surveillance – report.py')
    #print(titles)
    left, top = window.topleft
    right, bottom = window.bottomright
    pyautogui.screenshot(path)
    im = Image.open(path)
    im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    im = im.save(path)
    im.show(path)

elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':
    x1, y1, width, height = pygetwindow .getWindowGeometry('Chrome')
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    pyautogui.screenshot(path)
    im = Image.open(path)
    # im = im.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2+10))
    im.save(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getWindowsWithTitle` returns a list , try to access its member

`window[0]` and try to extract `top` and `left` from that

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem.

I should have taken the first element of the list:

```py
window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('bachelor-project-vision-based-traffic-scene-surveillance – report.py')[0]
```